# Sort array of objects with current location values

Tags: ios, swift, sorting

I have an array of Source objects:

```
 class Source: NSObject {
        var sourceName: String
        var country: String
    }
```

And I would like to sort that array by country name which is i am getting from NSLocale.

```
if let countryCode = (Locale.current as NSLocale).object(forKey: .countryCode) as? String {
                        print(countryCode)
                    }
```

How to sort objects by using country name like current location object first and then rest of all.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is first sort the array like you would normally by country name:

```
    array.sort{ $0.sourceName < $1.sourceName }
```

And then remove the current country from the array and add it as the first element:

```
    if let index = array.index(where: { $0.sourceName == "currentCountry" }) {
        let source = array.remove(at: index)
        array.insert(source, at: 0)
    }
```

I may have not used the right variables you want, I'm not sure if what the `Source` variables mean.
Also, make sure the `"currentCountry"` String is what you get properly from your method.

Comment: But it only sort one country but i m having multiple countries.